# Why is the Negative Binomial Model throwing errors?

Tags: python, statsmodels, poisson

I'm executing 2 models to fit my data set. The Poisson model is running without throwing any errors. But for the same dataset the negative binomial is not working. Can someone tell me what the errors mean?

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import NegativeBinomial 

m1=sm.NegativeBinomial(y_train,x_train).fit()
print(m1.summary())
```

I am getting the following errors in the model:

1) RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
llf = coeff + size*np.log(prob) + endog*np.log(1-prob)

2) RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  dparams = exog*a1 * (y-mu)/(mu+a1)

4) RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  dparams = exog*a1 * (y-mu)/(mu+a1)

5) RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  - np.log(a1+mu) - (y-mu)/(a1+mu)).sum() * da1

The Poisson Regression model is running well but the Negative Binomial is throwing errors. Please help.

Comment: These are warnings that could possible just be a result of bad parameters during optimization. Does it still converge for NegativeBinomial? What does summary show?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the original dataset has not been adequately cleaned / pre-processed. Can see in the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.html) you could add another argument in there like this:

```
m1=sm.NegativeBinomial(y_train,x_train, missing='drop').fit()
```

That may make the errors go away, but you should probably be looking at and thinking about the data first before just dropping rows with missing values.